# Using Collect with equations

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Is it possible to somehow use the expression that Mathematica has collected once the `Collect`  command has been used?

What I mean is, I have an expression like this (this is imaginary example)

```
(a[x,y]+b[x,y]+c[x,y]^2) z^5+a[x,y]^3 z^4+(b[x,y]+c[x,y]^4) z^3
```

That I got after I made `Collect[expression,z,Simplify]`.

What I'd like to do is to have command that will, for instance, give me the term that goes along `z^5` (the `(a[x,y]+b[x,y]+c[x,y]^2)`)?

I didn't find any examples of it, and `Collect` in help has no such examples.

EDIT:

Can this be done with the help of `Coefficient` command?

Comment: Perhaps `Coefficient` can be of help? As in `Coefficient[expr,z,5]`

Comment: That's it. I knew there had to be some way :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way:

```
 ex = (a[x, y] + b[x, y] + c[x, y]^2) z^5 + 
   a[x, y]^3 z^4 + (b[x, y] + c[x, y]^4) z^3;

Coefficient[ex, z^5]

(* a[x, y] + b[x, y] + c[x, y]^2 *)
```

This is another, if you do not like the first one:

```
    Plus @@ (List @@ ex[[Position[List @@ ex, z^5][[1, 1]], 2]])

(*  a[x, y] + b[x, y] + c[x, y]^2  *)
```

Comment: Yup that works, just like Peltio suggested :)